# presenting UIActivityViewController after a UIAlertController gives _BSMachError

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertAction that triggers the presentation of a UIActivityViewController. How can I make sure that the UIAlertController is dismissed so that when the UIActivityViewController is presented I don't get the error _BSMachError shown below. How can I dismiss the UIAlertController properly from the UIAlertAction handler?? I have looked through the various posts on SO and think its this issue that is causing the error message, but of course it may not be!!

The first UIAlertController is:

```
 func presentDone() {
    let doneAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Done!",
        message: "",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let sendLater = UIAlertAction(title: "Send Later", style: .Default) {action -> Void in}
    let sendCode = UIAlertAction(title: "Send Now", style: .Default, handler: sendCodeAlert)
    doneAlert.addAction(sendCode)
    doneAlert.addAction(sendLater)
    self.presentViewController(doneAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

when sendCode button is pressed the _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20) _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15) appears.

```
func sendCodeAlert(alert: UIAlertAction) {

    let message: String = "Hi! Ready to go!"
    let postItems: [AnyObject] = [message] 
    let controller: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: postItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let popup: UIPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: controller)
        popup.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 4,0,0), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone with some ideas on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this error all the time in multiple places and it never causes any problems. It appears to be safe to ignore.

Comment: It might be safe to ignore but the practice of ignoring warnings by the compiler as well as in the output window by itself is a bad practice to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost exactly the same problem with an OK-button that I gave an empty handler, like this:

```
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    })
```

I would already start throwing these warnings when it was just presenting the alert itself, but pressing the OK-button threw another one.

First I removed the handler (set it to nil) as I wasn't doing anything in the first place. This made the warning go away. The next thing I did was trying to see how to fix the problem and I added it again. No more errors.

I assume this is an Xcode / debugger / compiler problem, but make sure you are in the right thread when launching the alert as well. Always fix warnings before you commit, you can't be sure someone else won't experience it until you make sure it's gone at your side.